# java.lang.ClassCastException in Jetty when using Spring Session with Redis in combination with SseEmitter

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events, spring-session, spring-data-redis

I'm using Jetty 9.4 (but I've tried 9.2 as well), `spring-data-redis` 1.8.6 and Spring 4.2. I'm essentially using the default configuration provided by `org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` and everything seems to be working just fine until I add a `Controller` that has a endpoint that returns `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "sse", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> sse() {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    emitter.onCompletion(..);
    emitter.onTimeout(..);

    storeEmitterInHashMap(emitter);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Cache-Control", "no-store").body(emitter);
}
```

What seems to happen is that when there's a connection timeout to the SSE connection after 30s, Spring/Jetty tries to close a listener. But this fails due to a `ClassCastException` which is printed in the console:

```
[WARNING] java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper 
    cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler$SessionIf 
    while invoking onComplete listener
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler$SessionAsyncListener@67e50aa3
```

This happens roughly every 30s. If I navigate to another page which doesn't connect to the SSE endpoint the warning goes away.

Is this something to worry about? What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3044) in Jetty and fixed in version `9.4.13.v20181111`.